# What is it called when a business causes damages or vandalizes to garner more business?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, business

I don't if it's racketeering exactly because I don't know what the stipulations are for how long term or consistent it is or what qualifies as "organized", but suppose a car wash hires someone to spray paint on cars around the neighboorhood in order to get people to go to their car wash. What kind of crime is that?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just vandalism, as well as insurance fraud if they also submit claims.

Comment: It’s called the auto glass shop next to the parking lot.

Comment: "submit such claims"? What are you talking about? They wouldn't be submitting a claim at all, they don't want to draw attention to the process.

Answer (score 1):

The sprayer commits vandalism (criminal damage, or however your legal system treats it). The car wash owners are probably guilty of [conspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_(criminal)) and possibly have civil liability to the car owners if the sprayer cannot or does not pay. The car owners are not at fault (one comment mentions insurance fraud, but even if they know the car wash is doing this and claim on insurance, it would only be fraud if they assisted or encouraged the sprayer).

Comment: Why are you for some reason assuming that the owners of the respective cars are somehow at fault in any way when I asked specifically about the business itself? I didn't even ask about the vandal, just the business who hired them.

Comment: @GaneGoe he’s not assuming; take it easy.

Comment: @jqning if I "take it easy" then the issue isn't going to get addressed and people will think it's answered when it hasn't been answered at all.

Comment: @GaneGoe people won’t think it’s been answered; they’re not obtuse. Tim is addressing a potential issue.